# can't display models from ember-data

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I am usng Ember.js 1.0.0 RC1 and ember-data revision 12

I have PHP Slim framework in the back and Ember.js as UI. I want to load data from REST backend and list it in the template.

So here is my code:

```
 window.App = Ember.Application.create();

// Store
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
    revision: 12,
});

// Adaper
DS.RESTAdapter.reopen({
  url: '/slim'
});

// Router
App.Router = Ember.Router.extend();
App.Router.map(function(){
    this.route('ads', {path: '/ads'});
});

// Ad model
App.Ad = DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string')
});

// AdsRoute
App.AdsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){
        return App.Ad.find();
    }
});
```

Now I try to render my models from the store in my template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="ads">
<h1>Ads</h1>
{{#each controller}}
    {{title}}
{{/each}}
</script>
```

Response from backend:

```
{ads:[{title:"Title" },{ title:"other title" }]}
```

But nothing from the store is displayed. My question is how should I use data from controller in my handlebars template?

Thx for reading!

**SOLUTION**

I had to add quotes around JSON response

```
{"ads":[{ "title":"Title" },{ "title":"other title" }]}
```

Comment: This is a tricky bug to catch because there are no error messages in the console. Thank you so much. Adding quotes around JSON solved it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as if the content is never getting set in the controller. 
I suspect if you add the setupController hook to your App.AdsRoute it will place the items into the controller.

```
setupController: (controller, model) ->
        controller.set('content', model)
```

I'm including actual working code from a revision 11 App that I'm currently using. So the model names won't line up but the code is working.

```
App.ChecksIndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend
  content: []

App.ChecksIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  enter: ->
    console?.log("Checks Index Route a")
  model: ->
    App.Check.find()
  setupController: (controller, model) ->
    @._super()
    console?.log('route setupController')
    console?.log(model)
    controller.set('content', model)


{{#each item in controller }}
        {{#linkTo checks.show item }}
          <div class="well well-small well-trim-border">
            <h4>{{item.description}}</h5>
          </div>
        {{/linkTo}}
      {{/each}}
```

The model I'm getting back - includes an id.

```
{"checks":[{"id":"512e0c6b1769d0805700000b","description":"xyz"}]}
```

Comment: Thank you @nrion for quick answer. According to documentation setupController sets 'content' to model automaticly unless overwritten. Nevertheless I changed code like you said. Unortunately it does not work :( I am pretty sure it is due to revision 12. RC1 is fine with 11, but 12 doesn't work! Is there ANY documentation about ember-data? API or something?

Comment: what happens if you call controller.set('content', App.Ad.find() ) directly in the setupController hook? I'm aware this isn't how you'd want to do it in production, but to troubleshoot the problem? I've not attempted using revision 12 as yet, so that may be part of the issue.

Comment: Thx again for your time, nrion. Nothing changes when I do this way. When I try to print out content I get: "<DS.RecordArray:ember285>". And App.Ad.find().get('length') is 0. But that might be because its async and its not populated yet. I will try to do it on isLoaded

Comment: Also, you may want to create an `App.AdsController = Em.ArrayController.extend` with `content: []` property set.

Comment: Now I am pretty sure that my store is simply empty. Not sure why, tho'. I would be grateful if you could send me revision 11!

Comment: I just pulled down 12 and ran it under 12 without issue. Can you see the request hitting your API? And is it getting content back into it? If you're under chrome, you can also throw a debugger statement at the end of the route and call this.controller.get('content') and see what you get. Without that, a console.log(model) should show you what's being added to content. And maybe console.log(controller) to see if its going to the correct controller.

Comment: Thank you for your patience! I updated my question with backend response. The content is <DS.RecordArray:ember285>. I think I will rewrite it again step by step. Oh and it interprets respond correctly.  When I change something he yells about wrong mapping and hash keys. So it is fine. Somehow its not in the store and/or I am using wrong namespace.

Comment: Two other possible points where I ran into issues before. 1) is it going to the correct controller (reference {{controller}} in your template to see which controller it is trying to find content[] on - and make sure it matches the controller you're putting content[] into ) 2) I am not sure, but its possible its expecting an id field in the response.

Comment: IT WORKED! Thank you very much. What I had to do is:
1) define AdsController
2) put quotes around JSON keys i.e. {"ads":[...
Again thank you for going through this with me!

Comment: oh and add "id" inside JSON response

Comment: Good to hear you nailed it down. Its always something simple. Ember Data conventions are a little obscure sometimes, I've had tons of trouble with non-standard urls. I end up starting with fixture data and a jsfiddle and then moving it to api calls. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

One thing to try is to output a lowercase "title" in the template, as your model defines the property as starting with a lowercase "t".

Comment: Thank you for answer Michal. I admit I wasn't clear enough in my template. I just want to print anything for each item in my collection. I edited code to express what is my aim.